# Pandas GroupBy on consecutive blocks of rows

Tags: python, pandas

How do you groupby on consecutive blocks of rows where each block is separated by a threshold value?

I have the following sample pandas dataframe, and I'm having difficulty getting blocks of rows whose difference in their dates is greater than 365 days.

| Date | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | A |
| 2019-05-01 | B |
| 2020-04-01 | C |
| 2021-07-01 | D |
| 2022-02-01 | E |
| 2024-05-01 | F |

The output I'm looking for is the following,

| Min Date | Max Date | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 2020-04-01 | ABC |
| 2021-07-01 | 2022-02-01 | DE |
| 2024-05-01 | 2024-05-01 | F |

I was looking at pandas `.diff()` and `.cumsum()` for getting the number of days between two rows and filtering for rows with difference > 365 days, however, it doesn't work when the dataframe has multiple blocks of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest `.diff()` and `.cumsum()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

blocks = df["Date"].diff().gt("365D").cumsum()
out = df.groupby(blocks).agg({"Date": ["min", "max"], "Data": "sum"})
```

out:

```
           Date            Data
            min        max  sum
Date
0    2019-01-01 2019-05-01   AB
1    2020-06-01 2020-06-01    C
2    2021-07-01 2022-02-01   DE
3    2024-05-01 2024-05-01    F
```

after which you can replace the column labels (now a 2 level MultiIndex) as appropriate.

The date belonging to data "C" is more than 365 days apart from both "B" and "D", so it got its own group. Or am I misunderstanding your expected output?

Comment: Nope, you're right! I made an error in the data I created, and I fixed it now. Thank you!